# C#: Resolve Missing Assembly Reference for IServiceProvider.QueryService

Tags: c#, assemblies

I am not able to build some C# code because of the following message:

```
Error   CS1061  'IServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for 'QueryService' and no extension method 'QueryService' accepting 
a first argument of type 'IServiceProvider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    


serviceProvider.QueryService(ref SID_STopLevelBrowser, ref guidIServiceProvider, out objIServiceProvider);
```

Can this be fixed by adding a reference? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.dll

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.data.serviceprovider.microsoft-visualstudio-ole-interop-iserviceprovider-queryservice?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Comment: I added a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.dll, but that build error remains.  Is there also a 'using' that's missing?

Comment: using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data;